# fopen(): failed to open stream: Permission denied (when path permission is 777)

Tags: php, linux, permissions, chmod

> [Duplicated]

PHP function `fopen()` got permission error when all the path is with 777 permission.
Server details : `Centos 7 , PHP 7.1.8 , Apache 2.4.27`

**PHP Source Code :**

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

**Error Message :**

> Warning: fopen(newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test/file.php on line 3

**MyTest Url :** `http://MyIPAddress/test/file.php`

**777 permission paths :**

```
/var/www  
/var/www/html  
/var/www/html/test
/var/www/html/test/file.php
```

**File list with permissions :** ***(Edit 1)***

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -la /var/www/html/test
total 8
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root  41 Aug 24 20:26 .
drwxrwxrwx. 4 root root  48 Aug 24 19:37 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 179 Aug 24 20:22 file.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   1 Aug 24 20:22 newfile.txt
```

**SELinux is enabled & have access-list :**

```
[root@localhost ~]# semanage fcontext -l |grep "var/www"
/var/www(/.*)?                                     all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?                                all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/(/.*)?                                    all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
/var/www/html/(.*)?                                all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

**(Edit2)*** : If I disable SELinux the problem will solve , problem is from the SELinux , I'll make a new Question about it that why got error when I have access-list too.

Comment: can you try putting a absolute path instead of relative path just to test if it works for absolute.

Comment: @Kimberlee , `Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/test/newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: Do u have the txt file created in directory? if not, maybe u can try creating the txt file and try fopen again..

Comment: @Kimberlee same as first :)

Comment: If the file is already created what are the permissions on the file?

Comment: @Pitchinnate I've update the first post with the permissions list `ls -la`

Comment: Just for fun try running `sudo php file.php` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? If not I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Pitchinnate problem is from SELinux , even though I've added the directory in access-list .

Answer (score 8):

That sounds strange, if you have root permissions and have successfully done a:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www
```

The comand fopen should run without problems, as @Kimberlee set, you shuld try to provide an absolute path for the new file, just as this:

```
$file = fopen('/var/www/html/test/newfile.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file,'something');
chmod('/var/www/html/test/newfile.txt', 0777);
```